# Dialog deprecation problems

Tags: java, android, android-studio, deprecated

I working on an android app that someone did some years ago (in 2012 I guess) and I'm working on updating it so it can work again. I've corrected every deprecation cases I've encounter except one that is driving me crazy.

One of the Activity is working with dialogs but they are all deprecated.

- onCreateDialog
- onPrepareDialog
- removeDialog
- showDialog
- etc

Here is the part of the class with these methods:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        if (hour == 0) {
            hour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minute = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        }

        mTPD = new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, hour, minute, true);
        return mTPD;
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog); // call super

    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                removeDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
        break;
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        ((TimePickerDialog) dialog).setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                removeDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
        break;
    }
}
```

And there is a call for

```
showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
```

a little further. I created a DlgsFragment class:

```
public class DlgsFragment extends DialogFragment{
int mNum;

static DlgsFragment newInstance(int num){
    DlgsFragment f = new DlgsFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", num);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");
}
}
```

But since my first class already extends something else, I don't know what to do.. please help me!

Comment: The one I mentionned as my first class is the one containing the first chunk of code

Comment: still is not clear what is need to be solved? what is the problem?

Comment: the methods onCreateDialog and onPrepareDialog are deprecated and cannot be used...

Comment: see current guidlines about dialogs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean unusable.

Comment: Well, right now, it doesn't compile and after fixing deprecation in other classes and packages, I have much less errors

Comment: You probably have less warnings.